# UpdatePanel content is not rendered in Firefox after second partial postback

Tags: asp.net, firefox, updatepanel

I'm Using Firefox 42 (Code works fine in IE9,10,11 and Chrome).

Consider three DropDownLists dependent upon each other inside an ASP.net UpdatePanel.
A, B, C.

When I change A, B values are populated properly.
I then go to change B, C values are not populated.

The partial postback occurs, I can see the codebehind filling C properly, but the changes are not rendered in the UI.

I then continued to do another test.

I changed B values and C values populated properly.
I then went and changed A, B values did not update.

Which led to the conclusion that the problem is rendering of the content on the second partial postback.

I have dug through several questions here in SO and Google search but found nothing relevant or that could help.

Comment: You have some error on your code, and UpdatePanel hide this error, remove it, and do the same to see whats going wrong - probably some javascript error.

Comment: It works properly with the update panel in Chrome, IE 9, 10 , 11, thus this is not a Javascript error, these are simple DDLs that filter the content inside the next one according to the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone meets this problem.

Problem was a bug in AjaxControlToolkit AsyncFileUpload Component which was related only to Firefox. updating the Toolkit to the latest version fixed the issue.

[DevExpress Ajax Control Toolkit](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)